# allMarkdownRemark doesn't have a "field" and "order" in sort

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I can't sort by fields and order in graphql because those options doesn't exist in my graphql tree. If I add manually fields and order I getting error - Field order is not defined by type MarkdownRemarkSortInput and Field fields is not defined by type MarkdownRemarkSortInput. Any solutions for that?[image]

I was trying to add manually but that's not helping.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#sort), the `sort` variable is an array of objects of the form

`{ objectName: { fieldName: DIRECTION } }` where `DIRECTION` is `ASC` or `DESC`.

Your query should look more like:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark(
    sort: [{ frontmatter: { date: ASC } }, { frontmatter: { title: ASC } }]
  ) {
    …result fields
}
```

You can use the left side of your query explorer to build the query - you can see how under `allMarkdownRemark` the sort option is there and then under that there is `frontMatter`, `headings` etc…

Comment: Thank you Master Kenobi. You're great.